# Verificar si un numero pertenece a determinada secuencia lógica de números

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema de lógica. Dada la siguiente secuencia numérica, necesito una función que devuelva true si el numero que ingresa como parámetro se encuentra en la secuencia numérica, valga la redundancia. La secuencia numérica seria la siguiente: `n= 1,2,5,6,9,10,13... infinito`. La función debería de funcionar de la siguiente manera: `verificar_numero(numero);` si el numero esta dentro de la secuencia, debería devolver true y si no false.

```js
function verificar_numero(numero){
secuencia=[1,2,5,6,9,10,13];//El patron de la secuencia debe ir hasta infinito.
secuencia.forEach(function(elemento, index,numero){
var comparar= numero === elemento;
if(comparar){console.log(true);}else{ console.log(false);}
});

}//como uso un forEach me devulve multiples veces la repuesta y deberia ser solo una vez o falso o verdadero

verificar_numero(0);
```

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda. Es un problema de lógica, por lo que no importa en que lenguaje de programación responda.

Comment: Como no importa el lenguaje, puedes probar en cualquiera, armar un ejemplo mínimo verificable y volver con los errores o problemas específicos que tengas. De paso, enfocas la pregunta en el lenguaje que elijas, con eso los voluntarios que sean expertos en uno y otro te ayudarán rápidamente.

Comment: Ejemplo añadido

Comment: Porque usas un foreach si quieres que la funcion retorne un valor? En todo caso tendrias que usar un `for (let v of ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente código sirve para saber si un número está contenido en la lista de valores:

```js
function verificar_numero(numero=parseInt(document.getElementById("numb").value)){
secuencia=[1,2,5,6,9,10,13];
console.log(secuencia.includes(numero));

}
```

```html
Número: <input type="number" id="numb" /><br> 
<button onclick="verificar_numero()">Buscar</button>
```

En el caso de ser una serie infinita no se puede introducir en memoria, lo que debes hacer es moldearla con análisis algebráico.

Por ejemplo yo veo que suma +1 y luego suma 3+. Por lo que cada dos numeros sumarias +4, entonces si es divisor de 4 con un desfase +1 o +3 sabemos que está en la serie.

Aprovechando el residuo, se cumple que si el residuo es 1 o 2, entonces está dentro de la serie.

Propongo entonces:

```js
function verificar_numero(numero=parseInt(document.getElementById("numb").value)){
console.log(numero % 4 === 1 || numero % 4 === 2 ? true:false );

}
```

```html
Número: <input type="number" id="numb" /><br> 
<button onclick="verificar_numero()">Buscar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias @Alfredo Maussa la solución esta genial.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es relativamente simple.

La secuencia sigue el patrón:

```
+1, +3, +1, +3, +1, +3, +1, +3, +1, +3, +1, +3, +1, +3, +1, +3, +1, +3, etc.
```

Entonces tu solo tienes que alternar los valores.

Tu algoritmo seria algo así como:

Mientras que el valor que tengo es menor al valor que me dan, incremento según
la secuencia. Al finalizar, comparo si al valor que llegue es igual al
valor que me dieron. Si son iguales el valor esta en la secuencia:

> Es un problema de lógica, por lo que no importa en que lenguaje de
> programación responda.

Estaba pensando en subirlo en assembler, pero muy mala onda.

```
static bool numero_en_secuencia(const size_t n) {
    constexpr size_t inicial = 1;
    size_t cuenta = 0;
    size_t v = inicial;

    while (v < n) {
        if (cuenta % 2 == 0) {
            v += 1;
        } else {
            v += 3;
        }
        cuenta++;
    }

    return v == n;
}
```